# Information about Facebook comment author

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

My Facebook app uses the graph API to create comments (with the page access token of an user) as a page on its wall posts. The comments will be created successfully.

But if I take a look (as a page admin) at those on Facebook, the author information is not always the same. Sometimes the name of the app and the other times the name of the Facebook user (from which I got the page access token) will be displayed. This is confusing for me, because it seems to be completely random.

Does anyone know the exact behavior when which name will be displayed?

[different author information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkZOL.png)

Comment: Are you sure it’s random? Rather looks like it differs by whether you’re looking at a post or a comment. I don’t know about the attribution on a comment, but the one on the page post is visible to page admins only anyway.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know if it's random, but for me it seems so. This is exactly what I want to know. What I definitely can say is, that both cases were displayed for me at least once on my own page posts and my comments on user or my page posts.

Comment: As CBroe comments, it seems to follow the rule: If Page Post, use User, if Comment, use App. Anyway, this is not information you can control via the API, as Facebook determines how to render the comment.

Comment: Ok, thank you both for your answers.